# MySQL: COUNT(*) or COUNT(IF()) which is better?

Tags: mysql, database

I have this consults, I will like know which is better optimized?
This practice shows total of plans that have each state and total sketch that has every state

```
   SELECT l.cve_ent,
          COUNT(IF (plano='S',1,NULL)) PLR,
          COUNT(IF (plano='C',1,NULL)) CROQUIS
   FROM
          (localidades l
          LEFT JOIN
                 statusloc s
          ON (l.cve_ent=s.cve_ent AND l.cve_mun =s.cve_mun AND l.cve_loc= s.cve_loc))
   LEFT JOIN
          cigel13 c
   ON (l.cve_ent=C.cve_ent AND l.cve_mun =c.cve_mun AND l.cve_loc= c.cve_loc)
   WHERE l.esquema='03'
   GROUP BY CVE_ENT
```

or

```
   SELECT l.cve_ent,
        COUNT(*) PLR,
     FROM
        (localidades l
        LEFT JOIN 
        statusloc s
        ON (l.cve_ent=s.cve_ent AND l.cve_mun =s.cve_mun AND l.cve_loc= s.cve_loc))
     LEFT JOIN
        cigel13 c
     ON (l.cve_ent=C.cve_ent AND l.cve_mun =c.cve_mun AND l.cve_loc= c.cve_loc)
     WHERE l.esquema='03'
     GROUP BY cve_ent,plano
```

Comment: View the query plans - it might be surprising, especially with different combinations of indices or table sizes. "Problem" solved. Without further plan guidance, I would probably use the GROUP BY (or PIVOT :D), based on personal preference.

Answer (score 0):

You'd need to look at the EXPLAIN output to see the plans, I don't expect much of a difference. The same number of rows, the same predicates. The difference is the additional column in the GROUP BY (you probably need to return that in the SELECT list, so you can tell what you're getting a count of.

My instinct tells me that if there is a difference, the first form may be slightly better, if you're interested in only those two values of `plano`.

In that first query, you can get an equivalent result with:

```
SELECT l.cve_ent
     , SUM(plano='S') PLR
     , SUM(plano='C') CROQUIS
```

MySQL EXPLAIN explained:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/using-explain.html